# How to copy position of html component

Tags: html, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm doing some project in React and I have some outer library which creates `<div>` outside of the `<div class="root">` component (in root are all React generated html components) and show library functionality in this component outside of the root. I want to style this component and in the best way to pack it to React, but its not possible. So is there some possibility how to say to my outer component to copy position of some React component? I can style this outer component with some "fixed" coordinates but its so dirty way and I would have problems with different resolutions.

Example:

```
<body>
<div class="root> <div class="copy-to-this></div> </div>
</body>
<div class="librarycomponent"> </div>
```

I want from `.librarycomponent` to copy exact position of `.copy-to-this`. Thanks for answer!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: To be honest I dont know where to start with this css styling. I only tried to copy all elements from that another `<div>` to React component but doesnt work. Also I spoke with some friends and they gave me tip to some API bridge between my React component and outside component. But this is the last solution that I want to use.https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html